# How do I encrypt a file with Ruby using symmetric AES256 that can be decrypted with gpg?

Tags: ruby, encryption

How do I create an encrypted file in Ruby with the following constraints?

1. Data is an array of bytes supplied by an untrusted user.
2. Password is an array of bytes supplied by an untrusted user.
3. Password accepts all frequently used password characters, including [password special characters](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters) (e.g. ', ", etc.).
4. The file format should be a commonly used format such as OpenPGP.
5. The encrypted file is sent back to the user.

*Note:* Question clarified after a misunderstanding.

Comment: gpg uses the OpenPGP format described in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither [ruby-gpgme](https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme/issues/11) nor [openpgp](https://github.com/bendiken/openpgp/issues/2) seem to work well, so spawning gpg seems like the best approach currently.

```
require "openssl"
require "digest/sha2"
require "open3"
require "tempfile"

....

@@OPENPGP_DEFAULT_CIPHER = "AES256"
@@DEFAULT_MD = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA512

# Return symmetrically encrypted bytes in RFC 4880 format which can be
# read by GnuPG or PGP. For example:
# $ gpg --decrypt file.pgp
#
# ruby-gpgme doesn't seem to work: https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme/issues/11
# openpgp doesn't seem to work: https://github.com/bendiken/openpgp/issues/2
# Therefore we assume gpg is installed and try to spawn out to it
def encrypt_for_pgp(
  password,
  data,
  cipher = @@OPENPGP_DEFAULT_CIPHER,
  md = @@DEFAULT_MD.new
)
  input_file = Tempfile.new('input')
  begin
    input_file.write(data)
    input_file.close
    output_file = Tempfile.new('output')
    begin
      Open3.popen3(
        "gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --yes --homedir /tmp/ " +
        "--cipher-algo #{cipher} --s2k-digest-algo #{md.name} " +
        "-o #{output_file.path} --symmetric #{input_file.path}"
      ) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
        stdin.write(password)
        stdin.close_write
        exit_status = wait_thr.value
        if exit_status != 0
          raise "Exit status " + exit_status.to_s
        end
      end
      output_file.close
      return IO.binread(output_file.path)
    ensure
      output_file.unlink
    end
  ensure
    input_file.unlink
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have GPG installed then there's a fast, easy, reliable way:

```
open("| gpg [options]","w"){|f| f.syswrite(data) }
```

Example:

```
require 'shellwords'
data = "Hello World"
password = "letmein" 
gpg = "/usr/local/bin/gpg \
  --symmetric \
  --cipher-algo aes256 \
  --digest-algo sha256 \
  --cert-digest-algo sha256 \
  --batch --yes \
  --passphrase #{password.shellescape} \
  --output /tmp/out.gpg
" 
open("| #{gpg}","w"){|f| f.syswrite(data) }
```

In general, it's more secure to use the system's built-in GPG, rather than trying to manage your own crypto.

Comment: "In general, it's more secure to use the system's built-in GPG, rather than trying to manage your own crypto.". Most definitely. Take advantage of the prebuilt and tested wheels, especially for something as complex as encryption.

Comment: As an alternative to the password escaping rules (as the example stands, `password = 'x; mkdir /tmp/danger; #'` injects arbitrary shell code), I posted another answer below which sends the password through STDIN

Comment: Always protect strings that have external inputs, e.g. by escaping, untainting, validating, etc.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I don't think this answer is worth keeping up as it currently is with just a comment about password escaping, because the escaping rules are very complex and there is a danger someone might use this example without following them or do them incorrectly (a la your main point that security is hard). Or this example should be turned into pseudo-code. As it stands, it is dangerous.

Comment: I'll add a simple gate.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson Your use of gsub is worse - now any characters except letters, numbers, and underscores are removed, including special characters (which passwords are encouraged to have), and done so silently, so the user may get back a file encrypted with a different password. It seems self evident to me that passing the password through STDIN is inherently safer than shell escaping (see my other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this without needing to spawn a process by interoperating with openssl:

*Update*: See my other answer to use gpg instead

```
@@OPENSSL_MAGIC = "Salted__"
@@DEFAULT_CIPHER = "aes-256-cbc"
@@DEFAULT_MD = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256

# Note: OpenSSL "enc" uses a non-standard file format with a custom key
# derivation function and a fixed iteration count of 1, which some consider
# less secure than alternatives such as OpenPGP/GnuPG
#
# Resulting bytes when written to #{FILE} may be decrypted from the command
# line with `openssl enc -d -#{cipher} -md #{md} -in #{FILE}`
#
# Example:
#  openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -in file.encrypted
def encrypt_for_openssl(
  password,
  data,
  cipher = @@DEFAULT_CIPHER,
  md = @@DEFAULT_MD.new
)
  salt = SecureRandom.random_bytes(8)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher)
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(password, salt, 1, md)
  encrypted_data = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
  @@OPENSSL_MAGIC + salt + encrypted_data
end

# Data may be written from the command line with
# `openssl enc -#{cipher} -md #{md} -in #{INFILE} -out #{OUTFILE}`
# and the resulting bytes may be read by this function.
#
# Example:
#  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -in file.txt -out file.txt.encrypted
def decrypt_from_openssl(
  password,
  data,
  cipher = @@DEFAULT_CIPHER,
  md = @@DEFAULT_MD.new
)
  input_magic = data.slice!(0, 8)
  input_salt = data.slice!(0, 8)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(cipher)
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(password, input_salt, 1, md)
  c.update(data) + c.final
end
```

This is based on the [forge.js security library](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), specifically the [example to match openssl's enc tool](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/ffcd2db4f3c8547407fd35d92db9b272a8b971f1/README.md#cipher) and [using an iteration count of 1](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/ffcd2db4f3c8547407fd35d92db9b272a8b971f1/js/pbe.js#L403).

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson What is the bug?

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I edited my answer to add where my implementation came from, specifically the forge.js security library; however, after further investigation, I did find some concerns about OpenSSL's unchangeable iteration count of 1, which makes it easier to try to attempt to brute force, and I will further investigate this: ["the "iteration count" is set by the enc command to 1 and cannot be changed"](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase)

Comment: Opened issues https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/209 and https://github.com/mdp/gibberish/issues/18. forge.js issue resolved with updated README: "(Note: OpenSSL "enc" uses a non-standard file format with a custom key derivation function and a fixed iteration count of 1, which some consider less secure than alternatives such as OpenPGP/GnuPG)"